# MySQL запрос

Tags: mysql

Плз посоветуйте:

Есть таблица с полями id, time.

Где time - время входа пользователя в систему в формате Unix (кол-во секунд с 01.01.1970 г.).
При каждом входе пользователя в систему в таблицу добавляется строка с его id и временем входа.

Нужно вычислить для каждого пользователя, сколько было дней, когда он хотя бы раз входил в систему.

Если значения ROUND(time/(24 * 60 * 60), 0) для двух строк одинаковые, считаем что входы были выполнены в один день.

Comment: сделайте пока sqlfiddle с примером таблицы и данных, скоро кто-нить проснется, ему легче будет вас понять. а вообще может вам кол-во "заходов" считать во время захода тем чем вы вставляете в эту таблицу ?

Comment: количество заходов во время захода считать нет возможности

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select count(distinct  ROUND(time/(24 * 60 * 60), 0))  from table where id = ?
```